# Turbo Module and Fabric Component, can we share a UIView / Surface View between them?

Tags: react-native, react-native-turbomodule, react-native-fabric

I have an iOS and Android SDK which is made for classic (XCode/Android Studio) mobile development.

In this SDK, we use a Controller to do offscreen things like loading data and other stuff.
But we can also create a View or UIView, pass it to the controller and display something on this view using the SDK.

We want to make components for React Native in order for the SDK to be integrated in a RN App later.

I read about React Native New Architecture, Turbo Modules, and Fabric component, but I am not sure of what we can do whith them.

As I have a Controller and a separate View in my SDK, should I create a Turbo Module for the Controller and a Fabric Component the get View and pass it to the Turbo Module ? I am not sure that I can create a Fabric View, and then pass the address (pointer of the Android View / UIView) to my Turbo Module...

Maybe it's better to just develop a Fabric Component whith a Manager inside which will have the role of Controller and a direct access to a View / UIView which is created in the same component ?

Can you help me to understand better what I will be able to do with these Component and Modules ?

Thanks!